# Configuring Apache to allow disallow directory list

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, web, apache2

I need to allow directory listing only for a particular directory: `/var/www/test`. I followed the steps given here http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings but I am doing something wrong because of which I get **Forbidden 403** message if I browse `http://localhost/test`. Following is what I have in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/test. Can you spot any error with this config?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <FilesMatch index.html>
        deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /var/www/php/>
        AllowOverride None
        deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/test>
        Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Order` you're specifying for `/var/www/test` is `deny,allow`, so the `Deny from all` on `/var/www` is taking precedence over the `Allow from all` for `/var/www/test`. Switch that to `allow,deny` and you'll get the behavior you're expecting.

I'd also strongly recommend that you remove the `<FilesMatch index.html>`. It'll just cause you problems down the road. `index.html` has nothing to do with automatic directory indexing; it's only involved when you've explicitly created such a file, so this directive will just keep normal `index.html` files from ever working.

Comment: Changed it to `Order allow,deny`, restarted Apache, but it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: `<FileMatch index.html>` was added because I did not want index.html to run automatically when someone browse the web server directory. I wanted index.php to load up instead.

Comment: If that's all you're trying to do, `DirectoryIndex index.php` is a much more direct way of doing it.